# Is it possible to have a nested element to escape overflow:hidden of its parent container?

Tags: html, css, css-position, overflow

I have the following setup:

CodePen: https://codepen.io/pantaphobic-costar/pen/oNBrzqP

```
<div class="parent">
    Page Container
    <div class = "child1">
        header
        <div class = "grandchild">
            Content Div
            <div class = "greatgrandchild">
                Tooltip
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "child2">
       Tabs
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like for the Tooltip element to be visible outside of the child1 element (and on top of a portion of the child2 element), but the child1 element needs to maintain its overflow:hidden attribute. Is this possible?

CSS

```
.parent{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  border:solid 1px red;
}

.child1 {
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 160px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*Cannot be removed*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 39px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.grandchild{
  position: relative;
  width:200px;
  border:solid 1px green;
}

.greatgrandchild {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: 20px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #d8d8d8;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the tooltip is positioned absolutely but with the base for deciding where it should be placed being its immediate parent as grandchild has position: relative.

It depends on exactly what you want to do in terms of positioning, but if you remove that position: relative and put position: relative on an element further up the tree the tooltip will position in relation to that element and thus 'break free' of its own immediate parent's hidden setting.

Comment: While that sounds good in theory...it does not actually accomplish the goal..
https://codepen.io/pantaphobic-costar/pen/RwKzKmy

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, if you take the position: relative up to what is called parent then the tooltip can be seen.